# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter, but I'm including it in the call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I'm totally puzzeled. I have a WebMethod that I want to call from javascript. Simple enough, with jQuery, I've done this before. Yet this time, I get an error stating I didn't provide the argument for the WebMethod. But in my opinion, I am.

I have this in my aspx code-behind:

```
<WebMethod(True)> _
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True)> _
Public Shared Function GetTimes(ByVal input as String) As Object()
    Dim result As New List(Of Object)
    result.Add(New With {.Text = "5:30", .Value = "1"})
    result.Add(New With {.Text = "6:00", .Value = "2"})
    result.Add(New With {.Text = "6:30", .Value = "3"})
    result.Add(New With {.Text = "7:00", .Value = "4"})
    Return result.ToArray
End Function
```

And this in my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ThePage.aspx/GetTimes',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{"input":"test"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        succes: function (result) {
            alert('yep');
        },
        error: function (request, errorType, obj) {
            alert('nope');
        }
    });
```

Yet I get the following error:

> Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027input\u0027.

The StackTrace included is:

> at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary'2 parameters)
>   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary'2 parameters)
>   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
>   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)
>
> ExceptionType: System.InvalidOperationException

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: `data: '{"input":"test"}'` should be `data: ({"input":"test"})` or format is as the query string. More info here: [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem are making the literal object as string. The data should be **`{input:"test"}`** instead of **`'{"input":"test"}'`**

So the correct call will be

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ThePage.aspx/GetTimes',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {input:"test"},
        dataType: 'json',
        succes: function (result) {
            alert('yep');
        },
        error: function (request, errorType, obj) {
            alert('nope');
        }
    });
```

Comment: you typed the same exact thing he did.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using AjaxPro, which wasn't the preferred method, because it's no longer being actively developed. Plus, there's not enough documentation.

I tried the response from mohang, but got another error. I'm almost certain it's related to our specific project, because even the code in my question worked in another project.